# Getting the error : Unable to fetch the OAuth token when using an external credential with "Client Credentials with Client Secret Flow"

Tags: oauth2, externalcredentials, grant-type, client-credentials

I am trying to make a webservice call to an authorization server (OAuth 2.0) using the **"client_credentials" grant type**, but i receive a "**System.CalloutException: Unable to fetch the OAuth token**." when executing this code :

```
    Http httpCls = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('callout:FasstAPIGEE');
    request.setMethod('POST');
```

When i check the logs , i find these lines, both the name and the Id of the named credential are NULL:

[image]

However, when i make the same call via Postaman or curl , it works and i am able to get the access_token

I am sharing with you ma configuration of the named and the external credentials

[image]

[image]

[image]

here is a screenshot of the test i performed in postman

[image]

And here the curl command i am using that also works

```
curl -X POST -u "a1***_x**:xNMq******Gl" -d "grant_type=client_credentials" https://auth.***/oidc/token
```

Any ideas how to resolve the issue ?

Comment: does running user have CRUD `Read` on `UserExternalCredential` SObject?

Comment: @cropredy Would be a different error message if it couldn't read the creds.

Comment: @cropredy , yes, the running user already have the "Read" right  on the UserExternalCredential object

Answer (score -1):

HTTP call should not be sent to authorization server, You need to send call to your actual endpoint. Your named credential need to have actual endpoint and external credential need to have your OAuth endpoint. If using client credential flow, Salesforce should auto generate OAuth token(handled automatically) and attach it to your main http call.  That’s the benefit of using named credentials/external credentials.

Comment: i am sending my calls to an actual endpoint , i did not share it for the sake of simplicity , but the issue is still the same

Comment: One more question - your screenshot only shows external credential, did you create both named and external credential right ? And you are referencing named credential name in your callout. And I had created this article couple of weeks ago, see if this helps - https://medium.com/@sfdcsushil/calling-external-system-using-external-credentials-oauth-client-credentials-flow-51e5d52d4235

Comment: Never mind, I see named credentials in related list.

Comment: Only thing I can think of now is trying it without named credentials once to prove that your api is accessible from Salesforce.

Comment: I actually tried to do that to use apex to call the endpoint without named credentials to validate the endpoint, but i think salesforce does not support grant_type=client_credentials from Apex

Comment: I just tested, it works from apex without named credentials. Here is sample code -        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndPoint('YOUR_BASE_URL/services/oauth2/token');
        String body = 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET';
        request.setbody(body);
          request.setMethod('POST');
        HttpResponse response = new HTTP().send(request);
        System.debug(response.getBody());

Comment: once you validate your endpoint, then it should prove that at least directly its working. There maybe some small issue with name credential setup.

Comment: Thank you , i am going to try that away

Comment: I tried your code , i got an another error, "System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable" , it looks like there are some IP restrictions applied by the authorization server, but at least i have something to work on. i will update this question once i find the root cause of this problem, thank you

Comment: We identified the issue that was causing the error System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable". It turned out that the endpoint I was calling was not properly configured. Additionally, another custom header needed to be sent in the call. Once these issues were addressed, and the IP addresses were whitelisted, I was able to retrieve the access token using Apex. However, I am still encountering the error Unable to fetch the OAuth token when trying to retrieve the token from the named credential

Comment: Are you sending same custom header in external credential ? There is way to do that In external credential using formula.

Comment: @sushisfdc , i tried adding the header on the custom headers section on the the external credential layout , it still does not work

Comment: Have you checked this checkbox on named credential screen - Allow formula in http header? I have this article, see if it helps you in setting up external credential. https://medium.com/@sfdcsushil/connecting-to-external-api-from-salesforce-using-external-credentials-with-custom-header-option-4a7820c9d02a